# How to connect peers which are on different computers in geth on private network?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, peers

I am trying to setup a private network and trying to connect peers. Currently I'm trying it on my laptop and virtual machine(VM) runing on the same laptop (both of them are connected to internet). 
I init genesis file on my VM, start geth. 
Then init my genesis file on laptop(same copy of file), start geth.

With help of admin.addPeer("enode://....@[ip]:30303") i add peers on both machines.

admin.peersCount returns 0

Comment: You can take a look at: http://chainskills.com/2017/03/17/pair-the-miners-46/, this site is mainly focussing on connecting to a raspberry-pi but an other computer on the same network should also work.

Answer (score 0):

The main way to create a private network is to :

1. Create a `bootnode`
2. Run geth with `--bootnodes "< bootnode enode URL>"` On both VM and PM.
3. You can check if your peers are added automatically, or add them manually using `admin.addPeer()`

If this fails to make nodes connect, it is probably a network problem and you will need to diagnose that yourself (probably your VM and laptop don't share a local network that differentiates between them, internet doesn't since they both have the same gateway external IP).